# Powering Arduino AND Relays

Tags: power

I have a 5V (5.3V) switching transformer that goes to a 7805 voltage regulator and powers Arduino, Arduino controls 4 relays using BJTs. those relays getting power directly from the same power source.

Arduino and it's modules + LCD uses ~40ma, each relay consumes 70ma. total current is around 350ma lets say 400ma.

The problem is 5V isn't enough to power Arduino, modules, sensors and relays. LCD gets very dim etc...

it works with 9V but 7805 gets really hot ~70 centigrade while having a heat sink on!

If i remove the 7805 and switching power burns or something bad happens then there's nothing in between to protect the Arduino!

What's the solution for this situation?

---

**EDIT:** *for anyone who may have the same problem; I solved the problem with using a proper switching power salvaged from an old USB type-C charger and removed the 7805 voltage regulator, there's no heat anymore and it's working perfectly.*

Comment: switching 5.3V to 5V seems not high enough. The regulator needs some headroom to convert the voltage.

Comment: @chrisl i know but i don't wanna remove the regulator for safety reasons, on the other hand increasing the voltage causes heat! what do i do!

Comment: Use a switching regulator and increase the incoming voltage.

Comment: @Majenko a `LM2575T`, thanks.

Comment: Personally I like to use pre-built modules from model aircraft stores (called a BEC, SBEC or UBEC depeding on who you talk to). Cheap and ready built.

Comment: @Majenko i already have a switching module, should i remove the 7805 and connect it directly to Arduino? it's a chinese one and i'm afraid something might happen to it and damage the arduino after some time... it's a 220 to 5V.

Comment: 5.3V is within specification for the Arduino's 5V pin.

Comment: @Majenko my arduino is a standalone arduino and don't have the smd voltage regulator. are you sure it's safe?

Comment: The Absolute Maximum rating for Vcc on an ATMega328P is 6V.

Comment: You would have to check the datasheets for your other devices, but in general 5.3V is perfectly fine, since it's pretty much within the USB specification of 4.75V to 5.25V (just rounding will give you 5.3V).

Comment: Also, how have you determined that it is 5.3V?

Comment: @Majenko using a multi-meter, i connected the switching power LCD gets a little bit dim when all 4 relays are on but meh it's fine. but there's no protection for my arduino and modules now IF switching power burns out or idk something happens...

Comment: Did you have anything connected when you measured the voltage?

Comment: @Majenko no nothing, so after a few minutes the switching power gets a little bit hot too... is that normal?

Comment: With nothing attached you will be measuring the open circuit voltage. That will measure high. Measure the voltage with your circuit connected.

Comment: @Majenko it's 5V when connected to arduino and drops to 4.5 when all relays are on, i found a usb type C rapid charger which is 5V/3A can i use it for my project?

Comment: Yes, you can. What rating is your current 5V supply?

Comment: @Majenko i think it's 1A but it's a chinese one, i don't trust it wanna use the usb C charger module, [check this out](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/447352/usb-type-c-wires).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear regulators such as the 7805 operate by dissipating the additional voltage until their rated voltage remains.
This - as you noticed - requires a higher voltage  than the rated voltage.
Some variants, labeled as LDO for low drop-out, have reduced requirements for this, but normal 7805 usually require around 7 V to operate correctly.

The difference to the rated voltage is dissipated as heat as per `P = U * I`, with U being the voltage difference, and I the current pulled by your circuit.

You can use the switching power supply directly, or use a more advanced voltage regulator like the R-78E5.0 directly from 9 V, which has far lower losses.

Another option would be using the 5V from the switching transformer to drive the (less delicate) relays, and use the 7805 only for the MCU and display, but you would still want to use a heat sink in that case.